# ImportError: Extension horovod.tensorflow has not been built

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, horovod

Keep getting this error and I have reinstalled horovod and tensorflow multiple times. Please help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 3, in <module>
    import horovod.tensorflow as hvd
  File "/home/tavishi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/horovod/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    check_extension('horovod.tensorflow', 'HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW', __file__, 'mpi_lib')
  File "/home/tavishi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/horovod/common/__init__.py", line 42, in check_extension
    'Horovod with %s=1 to debug the build error.' % (ext_name, ext_env_var))
ImportError: Extension horovod.tensorflow has not been built.  If this is not expected, reinstall Horovod with HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 to debug the build error.
```

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this issues.

I used: https://github.com/horovod/horovod/issues/155

Rebuilding Horovod using the GitHub instructions solved my issue. I cloned the repo in the folder I had the program I was trying to run.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how did you fix this without custom docker image to use with sagemaker